# How can I set the focus automatically on a field in div?

Tags: html, focus

I have a div where I input a search query:

```
<div id="search">
  <form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search">
   <input type="text"   name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
 </div>
```

How can I set the focus automatically when the page loads?

Answer (score 2):

That is very annoying. But *if* you must...

```
window.onload = function() {

   document.getElementById('search').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();

}
```

I didn't change your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('q').focus()">

  <div id="search">
    <form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search">
     <input type="text" id="q" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
   </div>

</body>
```

Notice that I gave your input field an `id` attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give the input with a name of "q" an id of "q" as well.

Also note, the window onload event is not the greatest.  If for example, an image tag fails to load the image, the window onload event will not fire.  That is why frameworks like jquery have a $(document).ready() event handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('q').focus();
}
</script>
```